# Difficulty in executing boto3 S3 copy function using aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Here is the scenario. I have an S3 bucket (e.g. daily-data-input) where daily files will be written to a specific folder (e.g. S3://daily-data-input/data/test/). Whenever a file is written under the "test" folder a copy should also be written to the "test_copy" folder in the same bucket. If "test_copy" is not existing, it should be created.

I have used S3 event notification and attached it to a lambda function(with python 3.7) which will check if the "test_copy" key is existing if not will be created. I am able to create the "test_copy" folder successfully and couldn't make the S3 copy via boto3 to be working.

Here is the code for your reference:

```
import boto3
import os
import botocore
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_cli=boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name = event ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    bucket_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    file = (os.path.basename(bucket_key))
    source_key_path = (os.path.dirname(bucket_key))
    target_keypath = source_key_path+'_'+'copy'+'/'
    target_bucket_key = target_keypath+file
    copy_source = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': bucket_key}
    try:
        s3.Object(bucket_name, target_keypath).load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            # Create the key
            print ("Creating target _copy folder")
            s3_cli.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=target_keypath)
            #copy the file
            #s3.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=target_bucket_key, CopySource=copy_source)
        else:
            print ("Something went wrong!!")
    else:
        print ("Key exists!!")
        # s3.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=target_bucket_key, CopySource=copy_source)
```

I tried s3.copy_object, s3_cli.meta.client.copy, bucket.copy() and none of them are working. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Getting any errors?

Comment: No need to check if the `test_copy` folder exists and create it. You don't need it. Just copy from `data/test/cat.png` to `data/test_copy/cat.png`.

Comment: @Marcin Either the file wont be copied .. if not i see a lot of test_copy, test_copy_copy, test_copy_copy_copy folder with the file.

Comment: Try the equivalent of the following: `s3.Object('mybucket','data/test_copy/cat.png').copy_from(CopySource='mybucket/data/test/cat.png')
`

Comment: @jarmod ok. So if the key doesn't exists, it will be created automatically.?

Comment: @jarmod i shall try that and let you know the outcome.

Comment: The 'folder' doesn't have to exist, and it doesn't get created automatically either. This is object storage, not a regular file system. All you need are objects with keys.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simple way to copy an object in S3 within a bucket:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = 'mybucket'
src_key = 'data/test/cat.png'
dest_key = 'data/test_copy/cat.png'

s3.Object(bucket, dest_key).copy_from(CopySource=f'{bucket}/{src_key}')
```

Here is another, lower-level way to do the same thing:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'mybucket'
src_key = 'data/test/cat.png'
dest_key = 'data/test_copy/cat.png'

s3client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket, CopySource={'Bucket':bucket,'Key':src_key}, Key=dest_key)
```

Comment: I tried "s3.Object(bucket, dest_key).copy_from(CopySource=f'{bucket}/{src_key}')" and this is creating multiple _Copy folders with the file.

Comment: You mean `_copy` (lowercase) presumably, but that seems unlikely. Please check the values of the variables you are using for interpolation in the copy_from call. Reset your test bucket and retry from scratch with one uploaded file. What happens?

Comment: Yes. it is creating multiple _copy folders with the target file. Here is the format: test_copy, test_copy_copy, test_copy_copy_copy etc. I am not sure where where the mistake is but will definitely try as suggested.

Comment: Your Lambda function is being triggered by both the original `test` file and then by the `test_copy` file that you just copied. And that's causing the `test_copy_copy` file. Which triggers Lambda again, adding `_copy` each time, repeatedly. That's funny. Your Lambda function should only be triggered on a prefix of `data/test/`. Change the S3 trigger.

Comment: You are right. At the moment, the event is associated with "All object create events" and prefix is data/.